# ¿Cómo ignorar un carácter en una búsqueda Xpath?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

Me encuentro trabajando con Selenium y el día de hoy me encontré un problema particular. Estoy tratando de localizar el siguiente campo:

```
//*[text()='Country Of Birth']
```

Sin embargo selenium no encuentra el campo porque en el DOM el campo tiene un carácter invisible y en realidad está de la siguiente manera:

```
//*[text()='Coun­­/u00ADtry Of Birth']
```

¿Alguien sabe si es posible especificar mediante el Xpath que no tenga en cuenta dicho carácter al momento de hacer la búsqueda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar aplicar la función [`translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate) al contenido de texto del nodo que estás buscando de la siguiente manera:

```
//*[translate(text(), '\u00ad', '') = 'Country Of Birth']
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
function mostrarResultados(nodesSnapshot, texto) {
  if (nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength === 0) {
    console.log(texto, "No se encontró ningún elemento");
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++) {
      console.log(texto, nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i));
    }
  }
}

var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(
  "//*[text()='Country Of Birth']",
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null
);
mostrarResultados(nodesSnapshot, "Nodo normal:");

var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(
  "//*[translate(text(), '\u00ad', '') = 'Country Of Birth']",
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null
);
mostrarResultados(nodesSnapshot, "Nodo reemplazado:");
```

```html
<div>Coun­­&#x00ad;try Of Birth</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trata de utilizar la función `translate` de XPath: `//*[text()[translate(., '\u00AD', '') = 'Country Of Birth']]`. Esto asume que la expresión de XPath sea un String en JavaScript donde se puede utilizar `\u00AD` para marcar dicho carácter.